# How do I using Django's ORM to filter by a list of IDs where some of the IDs might not be found?

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

I have a list of `MyModel` ids: `[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11]`. Only `[1, 2, 3]` are found in `MyOtherModel`.

What's the best way to filter `MyOtherModel` based on that list of ids? I tried to do the following: `MyOtherModel.objects.filter(model__id__in=ids)` but it returned nothing since `5, 7, 11` are not found.

EDIT: typo.

Comment: I don't see why it would create a problem. This should have had worked just fine

Comment: you have written `mode__id__in` which should be either `model__id__in`, `model__pk__in` or `model_id__in` (this last one using the fact that a foreign key [creates a column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) named `<name>_id`.

Comment: @JessetheGame sorry that was simply a typo.

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal is it possible to give an alternative way of doing it with id__in to see what's missing exactly?

Comment: Does it returns anything when you use [1, 2, 3]